# Using Git Diff to compare different versions of db3 files

Tags: git, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, diff

I have been using Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2015 to connect to GitHub. Visual Studio 2015 allows us to compare the code files as they are text. For many other file extensions, it treats them to be binary and shows a standard dialog box saying that the binary files differ. I really need a mechanism to compare the different versions of the db3 files in our repository. Can anyone suggest me how to get it to compare the different file versions directly from git?

Comment: Why can't you store the SQL script (`sqlite3 my.db3 .dump`) in the repository, and create the actual DB only when needed?

Comment: We do not have a RDBMS on the server but we pack it into SQLite files with .DB3 extension and ship them to the user. The DAL in the application then interacts with them locally to create the entities and process the requests. I can ofcourse do it by getting each version in the local folder and use something like Beyond Compare. But would it not be nice to be able to compare these files directly without this annoying repetitive exercise?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a converter to display a textual version of your db3 files, lets' call it `db3_to_text`.

This script can for example display a list of all tables, then a `SELECT * FROM xxx ORDER BY yyy` for each (ordering may be important to avoid diff of simple random ordering)

Then you configure git to use it:

1. in a tracked `.gitattribute` file in your repository

   ```
   *.db3 diff=db3
   ```
2. In your `~/.git/config`

   ```
   [diff "db3"]
       binary = true
       textconv = /path/to/the/script/db3_to_text
   ```

It will work on the command line but I don't know if VS will honor this configuration if you display diffs in it.

Comment: That's the problem. We do not have any RDBMS but SQLIte files with .DB3 extension and those are shipped to the customer. Now when there is a change in the database, we update these files as per the requests and then push the changes to the GIT. If the changes become frequent, I need a tool that can compare these files without taking them on my local machine. Anyways, assuming that I understand what you have provided above, I shall try it out and let you know after Tuesday. Thanks.